# How does 192,168,1,2,7,138 convert to port 1930 on IP address 192.168.1.2

Tags: tcp, ftp, ftps

How do i deduce the port and ip from a number that FTP throws?
For example 192,168,1,2,7,138 converts to 1930 on IP address 192.168.1.2?

What is the logic behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first four numbers indicate client IP, the second two numbers indicate the client port number. It's a hex to dec conversion.

```
16^2 * 7 + 138 = 1930
```

The first number stands for 3-rd and 4-th bit of a hex number (port number), the second is for 1-st and 2-nd bit of a hex number.
So we have

```
7 = 07 in hex
```

and

```
138 = 8A in hex
```

Altogether we have

```
078A in hex which is 1930
```

or you can just skip that and convert only the first number to dec which is for 3-d and 4-th bit because of that "shift". The second number is already converted.